# need to change array value

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I am using below array and want to change the value of price key in item index please help. in array see items array and where price is displayed I want to add my custom price value in this and need to use again modified array with all associative key values

```
Array
    ([0] => Array(
          [customer_id] => 7
          [base_shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
          [shipping] => Array(
                        [entity_id] => 60
                        [customer_id] => 7
                    )        
                [items] => Array(
                        [0] => Array(
                                [sku] => bundlet01
                                [price] => 200.0000
                            )
                        [1] => Array(
                                [sku] => S12SX407
                                [price] => 0.0000
                                [parent_item] => Array
                                    (
                                        [sku] => bundlet01
                                    )
                            )
                        [2] => Array(
                                [sku] => S18SX001
                                [price] => 0.0000
                                [parent_item] => Array(
                                        [sku] => bundlet01
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php read this manual.

Comment: this is not a solution I have already checked this

Comment: you can manually change the price. do some efforts and show some code

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. Can't you just write a `for` loop that loops over the array and adds the new key?

Comment: I want to modify the value of price in this array and need to use again same array with same key with modified price

Answer (score 1):

let suppose this array save in $carts variable then

```
    foreach ($carts as $cart) {
        foreach ($cart['items'] as &$item) {
            $item['price'] = 1.00; // put you custom price what ever you want
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the price of just one item, you can access it this way:

```
$itemIndex = 0; // or which item you need to change the price
$newPrice = 5.00;
$array[0]['items'][$itemIndex]['price'] = $newPrice;
```

`$array` is your array.